# HLS stream created by ffmpeg pauses every 5 seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg, splitter, muxer

I am having problem remuxing an H264/AAC encoded file.  There is a file on a server with H264-encoded video with AAC audio  (example: `input_video.mp4`). An I-frame exists every 5 sec video. It is read by ffmpeg splitter/muxer application  which splits and muxes it into 5 second video clips and then sends to the client over HLS protocol.

While playing on client player there is a short pause every 5sec. This issue occurs only when ffmpeg higher than 2.4 is used, so in case ffmpeg pre 2.4.x is used (e.g., 2.0.8) then created video plays just fine.

I have looked into https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/Changelog & https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/APIchanges to spot changes in splitter/muxer but couldn't find relevant info.

Please give an answer or hints if you had a similar problem and solved it or have any idea what causes this issue.

Comment: Please supply that `input_video.mp4` file and the code you're using to generate the HLS stream.

Comment: Sorry for not replying timely. My senior didn't want me to share code :((, so I don't know how to explain. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Then I guess we're out of options; voting to close the question.